# Is id of model can only be int in extjs4?

Tags: extjs

I have a model and its id is type string. I load a record to display in grid but the id is show 'NaN'.

json

```
{"results":[{"id":"FT01","name":"area1","enable":true}],"total":1,"success":true}
```

model

```
Ext.define('YX.model.Area', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
fields : [
    { name : 'id', type : 'string' },
    { name : 'name', type : 'string' },
    { name : 'enable', type : 'boolean', defaultValue : true }
]
});
```

store

```
Ext.define('YX.store.AreaStore', {
extend : 'YX.store.ListStore',
model : 'YX.model.Area',
proxy : {
    type : 'ajax',
    url : 'area/list.do',
    reader : Utils.ajax.gridReader
}
});
Utils.ajax.gridReader = 
{
    type : 'json',
    root : 'results',
    successProperty : 'success',
    totalProperty : 'total'
}
```

If I set proxy.reader to a direct object then id is show correctly in grid.

```
proxy : {
    type : 'ajax',
    url : 'area/list.do',
    reader : {
        type : 'json',
        root : 'results',
        successProperty : 'success',
        totalProperty : 'total'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That may depends on what you do with the model, and the type of storage that backs your data. In principle, there should not be such a restriction, but that may be an expectation of some part of the framework (or third-party code).

Anyway, I've written a minimal test case with your model and a grid, and the `id` string is displayed correctly. That means that you probably have an issue somewhere else in your code... Most probably the proxy, reader or store.

Here's the test code ([running there](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/22a)):

```
Ext.define('Area', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'id',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'name',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'enable',
        type: 'boolean',
        defaultValue: true
    }]
});

Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.widget('grid', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        height: 300,
        columns: [
            {dataIndex: 'id', text: "ID"},
            {dataIndex: 'name', text: "Name"}
        ],
        store: {
            model: 'Area',
            proxy: {
                type: 'memory'
                ,data: [
                    {id: 'foo', name: "Foo"}
                    ,{id: 'bar', name: "Bar"}
                ]
            },
            autoLoad: true
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I founded the problem. I define a object and use every proxy's reader. Now I change the object to function and return a object, it's work well.

Answer (score 1):

this error is because of your field name is "id".
default idProperty='id' field and idProperty field must have int data.but in your case it is not.
so this code is giving you this error.
if you won't need idProperty then chanege you field's name "id" to something else

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-idProperty

Answer (score 0):

If you want your ID to be a number, you can customize it using `identifier`.
This is how it worked for me. I added this code in my model:

```
identifier: {
        type: 'sequential',
        seed: 10
    },
```